# Not able to connect to the SQL Server when executing the command

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
  "Server=ROHIT-PC\\ROHIT \\Database=Dorknozzle;" +
  "Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(
  "SELECT EmployeeID, Username FROM Employees", conn);

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            employeesLabel.Text += reader["Username"] + "<br />";
        }
        reader.Close();

        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();

    }
    }
    }
```

I'm getting error at `conn.open();`

saying

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)..

Comment: You don't need to put your question title in capital letters. Also you probably could have shown your code.

Comment: What's the edition of SQL Server? Also post your connection string.

Comment: Which part of the error message do you not understand - it tells you the two most likely issues - that you've misspelled the server/instance name in your connection string, or that the SQL instance isn't configured for remote connections. Even if you post your connection string, we're not going to be able to tell you which is true.

Comment: yup! posting connection string will move the fog away

Comment: I posted the total code now please help me with this now

Comment: Use the Visual Studio server browser to find your server.  Then you can right click and see the connection string it's using.

Comment: Check out the [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com) web site - it shows how valid connection strings look like and what you can define in them. Your current connection string is not valid - therefore you cannot connect.

Answer (score 2):

The problem must be in your connection string.

```
 <add name="SQL1" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

> Make sure your provided SQL connection
>   information is correct.

**Edit:** This  `"Server=ROHIT-PC\\ROHIT \\Database=Dorknozzle;"`

should be I think:

```
 "Server=ROHIT-PC;Database=Dorknozzle;"
```

Comment: It should probably really be:  `"Server=ROHIT-PC;Database=Dorknozzle;` or something like that...

Comment: @marc; thanks for your correction. I am deleting other thing and that was deleting accidently and I did not noticed

Answer (score 2):

I believe `Server=ROHIT-PC\\ROHIT \\Database=Dorknozzle;` should read something like

```
Server=ROHIT-PC\\ROHIT; Database=Dorknozzle;
```

(assuming the name of the server is `ROHIT-PC` and the name of the SQL Server instance is `ROHIT`)

Comment: ... and assuming that `Dorknozzle` is the database...

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you everything you need to know:  **The server was not found or was not accessible.**   The trick is.  Why can't your application find it?  Can you provide any more information.

Can you ping the server?  Is the server on?  Are other connections to the server working?  Can you connect with SSMS?  Is the connection string properly formatted?  If your programming with Visual Studio can you find the server with the Server Browser?  (If so, you can use it to generate a properly formatted connection string.)  This error could also be caused because the server is too busy handling something major and causing a timeout error.  Can you see the activity on the server?  Is it going crazy?

All we know from what you've posted is that you asked for a server and didn't get a response.  But we don't really have enough information to tell you why.